# Two parallel OpenVPN tunnels site-to-site: can't access all interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

## The setup

I have the following topology:

```
              Router
              172.25.214.1
                  |
                  |
                  |
              SiteB
              172.25.214.0/24
                  |
                  |
                  |
          LAN: 172.25.214.3
       OpenVPN server+client B
TUN0: 172.25.215.1    TUN1: 10.1.2.2
        |                   |
        |                   |
        |                   |
    VpnSiteB            VpnSiteA
    172.25.215.0/24     10.1.2.0/24
        |                   |
        |                   |
        |                   |
TUN1: 172.25.215.2    TUN0: 10.1.2.1    
       OpenVPN server+client A
          LAN: 10.1.1.3
                  |
                  |
                  |
              SiteA
              10.1.1.0/24
                  |
                  |
                  |
              Router
              10.1.1.1
```

On each site the OpenVPN server+client is a Raspberry Pi running one server instance of OpenVPN, and one client instance of OpenVPN.

The kernel routing table on OpenVPN host SiteA:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
172.25.214.0    172.25.215.1    255.255.255.0   UG    20     0        0 tun1
172.25.214.0    10.1.2.2        255.255.255.0   UG    30     0        0 tun0
172.25.215.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
```

and that of the OpenVPN host on SiteB:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.25.214.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        10.1.2.1        255.255.255.0   UG    20     0        0 tun1
10.1.1.0        172.25.215.2    255.255.255.0   UG    30     0        0 tun0
10.1.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
172.25.214.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.25.215.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
```

As you see, the only networks that have multiple routes is SiteA and SiteB. The OpenVPN hosts both prefer to route to the other site via its *client* interface/OpenVPN network.

## The problem

*Most* routing work fine. Any host on SiteA can communicate bidirectionally with

- Any host interface on SiteB
- Any host interface on VpnSiteA
- Any host interface on VpnSiteB *except* TUN0 / 172.25.215.1

I.e. a host on SiteA can ping

- 10.1.1.3
- 10.1.2.1
- 172.25.215.2
- 172.25.214.3
- 10.1.2.2
- But *not* 172.25.215.1

**That is what I want to solve.**

## Troubleshooting I've done

### Test 1

On a host on SiteA, I ping 172.25.215.1 and traced what happened with `TCPDUMP` on both OpenVPN hosts.

- Echo request arrived at OpenVPN host SiteA on its LAN interface
- Echo request left OpenVPN host SiteA on its TUN1 interface
- Echo request arrived at OpenVPN host SiteB on its TUN0 interface
- Echo reply left OpenVPN host SiteB on its TUN1 interface
- *No* Echo reply arrived at OpenVPN host SiteA on *any* of its interfaces.

So its here something goes wrong.

### Test 2

I disabled the OpenVPN server on the OpenVPN host of SiteA, and disabled the OpenVPN client on the OpenVPN host if SiteB. In other words, there is now only one tunnel. This time, I was *successful* on pinging 172.25.215.1 from a host on SiteA.

So its when I have two tunnels something goes wrong.

## Background

Why not just one tunnel? Every now and then, my ISP at both sites stops assigning me a public IP address, putting me behind CGN. If this happens on the site hosting the OpenVPN server, connectivity between the sites goes down. But if both sites each run an OpenVPN server, if one site gets behind CGN, no problem.

## Appendix

`server.conf` of OpenVPN host SiteA:

```
; General
; ---------------------------------------------------------

dev tun0
proto udp
port xxxx                                
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

keepalive 10 120
max-clients 20
tls-server

verb 2

; Network
; ---------------------------------------------------------

topology subnet
client-to-client

server 10.1.2.0 255.255.255.0                                  

route 172.25.214.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.2 30
```

`client.conf` of OpenVPN host SiteA:

```
; General
; ---------------------------------------------------------

client
dev tun1
proto udp
remote xxxx

resolv-retry infinite
connect-retry 5 1800
explicit-exit-notify
nobind
tls-client

verb 2

; Network
; ---------------------------------------------------------

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/uppe.sh
down /etc/openvpn/nere.sh
up-restart
up-delay

iproute /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip
```

Note: security related settings are removed.

`uppe.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip route add  172.25.214.0/24 via 172.25.215.1 dev tun1 metric 20
exit 0
```

`nere.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip route del 172.25.214.0/24 via 172.25.215.1 dev tun1 metric 20
exit 0
```

These two relate to the CGN mitigation.

The files for the OpenVPN host on SiteB is identical except that the network addresses differ.